# ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/router/src/router_config_loader

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I'd switched to **Angular4.0.0-rc.1** I got an error during the build (`npm start`):

> ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/router/src/router_config_loader

Is it known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution from:
[Cannot Upgrade a Existing Angular Cli project to Angular 4 Rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516188/cannot-upgrade-a-existing-angular-cli-project-to-angular-4-rc1)

```
npm install @angular/common@next --save
npm install @angular/compiler@next --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@next --save
npm install @angular/core@next --save
npm install @angular/forms@next --save
npm install @angular/http@next --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser@next --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next --save
npm install @angular/platform-server@next --save
npm install @angular/router@next --save
npm install @angular/animations@next --save
```